# Laravel groupBy multiple relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have the follow relations

**Order** -> **orderItems** (hasnmany)-> **product** (hasOne) -> **product_category** (hasOne)

I would like get all orders groupBy category product id. But i need help because my query is not working well.

**My query:**

```
$items = Order::orderBy("id", "desc")
    ->with("orderItems.product.product_category")
    ->get();
$groupByCategory = $items
    ->groupBy("orderItems.product.product_category.id");
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You are not starting from the right Object.

Dealing with Eloquent, always start as you want your tree to look like ;

in your case :

Category->product->order, so your query would look like this :

```
$categories = Category::with([
    'products.orderItems' => function($query){
         $query->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }])->get();
```

Then :

```
foreach($categories as $category){
    // $category->name
    foreach($category->products as $product){
        // $product->name
       foreach($product->orderItems as $item){
          // $item->name
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: the orders are 25k we can do a loop for every category. I need a query where i can do a groupBy